# Enterprise Architecture: unify sequence, component and deployment diagrams?

Tags: uml

I've been asked to create a diagram that contains all the basic information normally found in sequence, component and deployment starting from a certain process. For example for the provisioning process or the activation of a particular promotion for a customer there should be a diagram that contains all the following info:

- a functional layer: all the involved systems (CRM, ESB, Billing, etc) and the specific way they interact (a sort of sequence diagram)
- an application layer: all the techical parts involved in the process (for example: which specific interface or component of the various systems is in the picture) (a sort of component diagram)
- an infrastructure layer: all the physical components where relies the process (a sort of deployment diagram)

Can I get all together?

thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Architect doesn't limit the types of elements you can put in a diagram.  However, it does sound like you want to create the 3 diagrams that you mention.  I would pursue that course and then ask your customer if they want to combine the documents.